# How to determine whether passed into the function path or image?

Tags: php

For example I have function named `test` in which I do some stuff with image. I want to be able detect if in it was passed the image or only the path to it. For example:

```
function test($image) {
    // here I need to detec if $image is path or loaded image
}

test('/home/name/image.jpg');
test(file_get_contents('/home/name/image.jpg'));
```

Comment: if($image=='')
    {
      echo "error";
    } else {
       echo "working f9";
    }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have these sanitized:

```
if (file_exists($image)) {
  // path
} else {
  // image
}
```

Probably you’ll want to check whether an image is the proper image using some image handling library in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) for this

> Tells whether the given file is a regular file.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `getimagesize($image);`. If it has a width and height, it's an image.See http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php for full info.

```
$image_size = getimagesize($image);
$image_size[0] > 0 ? /*It's an image*/ : /*It's not*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function test($image) {
  if($image=='')
  {
    return false;
  }
  if(file_exists($image))
  {
    echo "file exists";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "path is passed to the function";
  }
}

test('/home/name/image.jpg');
test(file_get_contents('/home/name/image.jpg'));
```